# How to check if MediaElement has stopped?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, mediaelement

I need to check, if MediaElement stopped at the moment or played.
This is my code:

```
private void PlayAudioClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    AudioPlayer.Play();
    StopAudio.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    PlayAudio.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    if (AudioPlayer.Stoped == true)
    {
        PlayAudio.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        StopAudio.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

I am looking for something like this pseudocode: if (AudioPlayer.Stoped == true) {//do something}.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `MediaElement` 's `MediaEnded` event to check when the media has ended playing..

In XAML

```
<MediaElement Name="media" MediaEnded="media_MediaEnded"  />
```

In C# code

```
media.MediaEnded += media_MediaEnded;
```

The event handler would look like..

```
private void media_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Do your stuff       
}
```

Also to detect the Current media state you have a enum Called `MediaElementState` you can  get this by calling the `CurrentState` property in the `MediaElement` When put in a switch you can see all the states.

The MediaElement also has a `CurrentStateChanged` event also.. This event fires when the state of the MediaElement get changed and you can use this in combination with CurrentState property to check what state the media is in.

In XAML

```
CurrentStateChanged="media_CurrentStateChanged"
```

or in C#

```
media.CurrentStateChanged += media_CurrentStateChanged;


private void media_CurrentStateChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (media.CurrentState)
    {
        case MediaElementState.AcquiringLicense:
            break;
        case MediaElementState.Buffering:
            break;
        case MediaElementState.Closed:
            break;
        case MediaElementState.Individualizing:
            break;
        case MediaElementState.Opening:
            break;
        case MediaElementState.Paused:
            break;
        case MediaElementState.Playing:
            break;
        case MediaElementState.Stopped:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

You can use this to detect the current state of the media.. Hope it helps..

Comment: is there any other way? my mediaelement is not firing these events

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
media.Position = TimeSpan.Zero;
```

to the event handler solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

CurrentStateChanged is not found in MediaElement for Xamarin.

The other way around is to attach PropertyChanged event and then check for changes:

```
videoPlayer.PropertyChanged += VideoPlayer_PropertyChanged;
private void VideoPlayer_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (videoplayer.CurrentState)
            {
                case MediaElementState.Playing:
                    break;
                case MediaElementState.Stopped:
                    break;
            }
        }
```